# Can anyone tell me if this sentence is correct?

Tags: word-choice

I obtained my Bachelor’s degree in Textile Engineering and Management at the end of last year.

Comment: Can you tell us what issue you are having with the sentence, which is not bad?  Also, did you get a chance to check out our tour? You will be rewarded for it.

Comment: I just don't know if the sentence is correct, since I am translating from another language. Will check out the tour :)

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! Please see "How can I ask about checking my text?" in the [help pages](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). We don't do simple proof-reading: we can help with specific points of difficulty. If you are learning English then [ell.se] may help, but they don't do proof-reading either.

Comment: If you ask "Is this okay?" you get funny looks here. 'Degree' is understood (we say BS in...), and no need to say when last year, as last year is enough. And 'earned' is juicier than obtained.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Depending on the context, it's certainly possible that "end of last year" is helpful to the meaning of the sentence. I believe OP is merely asking if the sentence makes grammatical sense. I see no errors in it.

Comment: I feel it is cruel to approve wording that causes the writer harm but is correct  in grammar. Members here are free to take things literally if they want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your sentence is correct according to "vocabluary.com." Here is an excerpt from it: 
"Obtain means to get something that is not so easy to come by such as knowledge, rights, or a large amount of money. You wouldn't say you obtained a pair of pants, unless they were one of a kind.
At times in its history, obtain has meant to be victorious or to succeed. Today, it mostly means to acquire, but keeping its prior meanings in mind helps you to use it in the right way. College degrees are something that you obtain as is permission from your parents to go to a party. When you obtain something, you have worked hard to get it, so you are pretty happy to have it."